# Batch File XCopy Command

Tags: command-line, copy, xcopy

I have a batch file which loops through a content of a text file and copies a specific file using xcopy command.

here's the snippet.

```
for /f %%a in (FilesToCopy.txt) do (
xcopy ..\..\Common\%%a Common\%%a /i /d /c /v /s /y /f 
xcopy Common\%%a ..\..\Common\%%a /i /d /C /v /s /y /f 
)
```

%%a contains values like
Images\image1.jpg
Images\image2.jpg

so when xcopy is executed it would look like

```
xcopy ..\..\Common\Images\image1.jpg Common\Images\image1.jpg /i /d /c /v /s /y
```

upon execute it would then prompt this message

```
Does Common\Images\image1.png specify a file name
or directory name on the target
(F = file, D = directory)?
```

it seems that the /i command doesn' work or i am missing something here to suppress the message above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you left out the *second* statement the help gives about `/I`:

```
/I           If destination does not exist and copying more than one file,
             assumes that destination must be a directory.
```

You are only ever copying one file at a time, so `/I` doesn't apply.

You can probably hack-solving this by piping `F` into the command and suppressing output:

```
echo F|xcopy ..\..\Common\%%a Common\%%a /i /d /c /v /s /y /f >nul
```

(Won't work on non-English versions of Windows; but probably that's the least of your problems, given that the batch already fails for file names with spaces :-))

You could try building a single long list of file names to copy:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
set LIST=
for /f %%a in (FilesToCopy.txt) do set LIST=!LIST! "..\..\Common\%%a"
xcopy %LIST% Common /i /d /c /v /s /y /f
```

This requires two passes over the initial file, though. And it fails when the list of file names gets longer than 8190 characters.

Comment: good point with the hack thing, i'll try your solution tho...

as you can see there is a timestamp checking /d there so /d means copy only if the destination is older.

so if commandA's source has new version than the destination then it would replace it and vice versa for commandB.

Comment: Ah, didn't bother to dissect the switches there in detail, sorry :-)

Answer (score 1):

The destination should be a path, then it won't ask:

```
xcopy ..\..\Common\Images\image1.jpg Common\Images\ /i /d /c /v /s /y
```

In your case, you can use path extraction with %~p on the destination since you may want to preserve that:

```
xcopy ..\..\Common\%%a Common\%%~pa /i /d /c /v /s /y
```

Comment: yes, that would work but then as you can see there is a reason why its i'm using the text file and store it to %%a, that way i would have a dynamic destination path. Images aren't the only expected path there.

Comment: Good point.  I updated my answer to show that you can extract the path from your items in the text file.